# How my Samba shared folder is protected without any valid user defined

Tags: linux, unix, samba

I'm having a hard time trying to understand how Samba is able to put restriction on a folder having no "valid user" property set

here is my smb.conf

```
[test-share]
    comment = test shared folder.
    path = /home/root/test-shared
    browseable = Yes
    read only = No
    force create mode = 0660
    force directory mode = 0660
    vfs objects = acl_xattr full_audit
    acl_xattr:ignore system acls = no
    full_audit:success = connect opendir disconnect unlink mkdir rmdir open rename
    full_audit:failure = connect opendir disconnect unlink mkdir rmdir open rename
```

There is no valid user defined and still some permission check are done

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One thing that is not immediately apparent to most new samba/SMB admins, is that Share permissions stack on top of disk permissions. Share permissions only affect Samba/WFPS access; they do not override permissions on the shared directory, only augment them.

So, if a folder is owned by user1:user1 and has permissions of 770, and then shared to allow everyone Read/write access to it, only the account `user1` would actually be able to access the content of the share.

So the moral is, Share permissions can be used to narrow access to content (by restricting remote users who have permissions on the directory) but they can never ever widen access to provide access that the folder permissions do not specify.

Its notable that [Microsoft recommends](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc736916%28v=ws.10%29.aspx) that whenever possible, share permissions consist of the single grant "Everyone, Full Control". This is because when a disk is backed up, its permissions are backed up too, but its share permissions are not part of the disk filesystem itself and do not get backed up, so restoring data could over-privledge users if share permissions are in fact used to narrow access. Setting permissions on the directory however limits the capabilities of users both local and remote, regardless of how the share is configured.

Hope that helps

Comment: "So the moral is" - Do you mean to use the phrase ["the moral of the story"](http://www.learningtogive.org/units/through-eyes-child/moral-story) by chance?

Comment: Indeed, that was the full phrase I was referencing. I'm sure I could have used "In conclusion", or "In summation", or "the point is, that..." or any number of other constructs, but I can only pick one. Cheers.

Comment: thanks a lot for your explanation, just to make sure I get your point, If they is no restriction on with a "valid user" for instance, it doesn't mean everyone can access the folder, it means there is no samba restriction but there is some unix permission on it and only some Unix User/group will be able to access it.

Comment: exactly. filesystem permissions trump share permissions.